# Java Recursion to find MAX sum in array

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I am trying to figure out a solution to calculate the highest sum of numbers in an array. However, my limitation is that I cannot use adjacent values in the array.

If I am given the array `int [] blocks = new int[] {15, 3, 6, 17, 2, 1, 20};` the highest sum calculated is 52 (15+17+20).
My goal is to go from a recursive solution to a solution that uses dynamic programming, however, I am having trouble with the recursive solution.

The base cases that I have initialized:

```
if(array.length == 0)
    return 0;
if(array.length == 1)
    return array[0];
```

After creating the base cases, I am unsure of how to continue the recursive process. 
I initially tried to say that if the `array` was of certain length, then I can calculate the max(`Math.max`) of the calculations:
e.g. `if array.length = 3
                  return Math.max(array[0], array[1], array[2], array[0]+ array[2])`

The problem I then run into is that I could be given an array of length 100.
How can I use recursion in this problem?

Comment: Why are you keen on adding only three numbers in your example `15+17+20` , is the output restricted up to three numbers?

Comment: Those are the numbers that get me the highest sum. I can easily do 15 + 6 + 2 + 20 but that only gives me 43.

Comment: well, doing 15+3+6+17+2+1+20 gives me 64. That beats you by 12.

Comment: Yes, I definitely agree, only problem is P.J., I cannot use adjacent spots in the array, meaning I can't use all of the values, furthermore if Im using 15 I can't use 3. Catch my drift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think recursive solution to your problem is (in pseudocode):

```
maxsum(A,0) = 0
maxsum(A,1) = A[0]
maxsum(A,k) = max(maxsum(A,k-2)+A[k-1], maxsum(A,k-1)), for k >= 2
```

Where `maxsum(A,k)` means the maximal sum for a subarray of array `A` starting from `0` and having length `k`. I'm sure you'll easily translate that into Java, it translates almost literally.